# How can I get a more precise value from a list of weighted numbers?

Tags: math, audio

A is a list of increasing fixed values (frequencies). It doesn't step evenly but the values never change.

A = 5, 10, 17, 23, 30

Each value in A is weighted by the corresponding value in list B (volume).

B = 2.2, 3.5, 4.4, 3.2, 1.1

I want to calculate the loudest frequency (A). The problem is that the loudest frequency may be 14 but I can't tell from this data set. How can I calculate, based on list B, what the loudest frequency might be in list A?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough outline of a solution: I haven't nutted out all the maths for you, but I hope it helps.

Approximate the frequency amplitude using interpolatory splines.
This will give you the function between each adjacent pair of frequency sample points as a sum of basis functions for the frequency values surrounding the pair.

This means you have a function f(x) defined on each interval.

```
f(x) = A phi_0(x) + B phi_1(x) + C phi_2(x) + D phi_3(x)
```

At the maximum

```
0 = f'(x) = A phi_0'(x) + B phi_1(x) + C phi_2(x) + D phi_3(x)
```

If you're using a cubic spline interpolation, the derivate will be quadratic in x. And thus you can obtain 2 *potential* extremums for each interval.

Scan through all the intervals, calculate that extremum. Check if it falls inside the interval .. if it doesn't its not really a potential extremum. You now have a list of all the potential internal maxima. Add to this list the values at each node. The maximum from this list will be the maximum value of the interpolatory spline.

Answer (score 1):

You have not been terribly clear here (IMHO). I don't know what it means to "weight" values in A by B. Do we assume we are to treat B as a function of A? Therefore, we are looking for the frequency (A) such that B attains its maximum value, AS A FUNCTION OF A?

If so, this is simply a problem of interpolation, then maximizing the interpolant. Depending on what tools you have available to you, you might do a spline interpolation, as shown in this figure. Then it would be merely a problem of finding the maximum value of that spline.

[image: Interpolated relationship B(A)]

This spline model suggests the maximum value is Bmax=4.4132, which occurs at A=16.341.

Alternatively, one might simply fit an interpolating polynomial through the points. Your curve is not that noisy that a 4th degree polynomial will be ill-posed. (Had you more points, a high order polynomial would be a terrible idea. Then you might use a piecewise Lagrange interpolant.) Done in MATLAB,

```
>> P = polyfit(A,B,4)
P =
   6.6992e-05   -0.0044803     0.084249     -0.34529       2.3384
```

I'll plot the polynomial itself.

```
>> ezplot(@(x) polyval(P,x),[5,30])
```

[image]

We can find the maximum value by looking for a root (zero value) of the derivative function. Since the derivative is a cubic polynomial, there are three roots. Only one of them is of interest.

```
>> roots(polyder(P))
ans =
       31.489
       16.133
       2.5365
```

The root of interest is at 16.133, which is consistent with the prediction from the interpolating spline.